# ValueError at /sup/ invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: django-templates, django-admin, django-views

i'm new on stackoverflow and in django 
I know this has been asked before, but for my circumstance, I can't seem to figure out why this is being thrown

When I try to delete a user, I am given this error from my console:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Here is my view.py where that code is located:

```
class Delete_user(DeleteView):
    model = AuthUser
    template_name = 'delUser.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('ListUserAdmin')
```

the templete :

```
<form action="{% url 'Sup-User' pk=AuthUser.id %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Yes, delete." />
<a href="{% url 'ListUserAdmin' %}">No, cancel.</a>
</form>
```

and this is the url :

```
url(r'^sup/(?P<pk>.*)', log.views.Delete_user.as_view(),
name='Sup-User',),
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the source in the body of the post with proper indentation (it's pretty much impossible to debug Python without knowing the indentation).

Comment: ok so...in my templete when a replace "pk=AuthUser.id"  by some exiting id User in my db like 1 or 2 numbers ,its ok ...so i think que issue is that the templete dont receve the id. i'm very lost. thanks in advance